# Use System.Threading.Timer with CustomThreadPool?

Tags: .net, multithreading

So, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), System.Threading.Timer calls it's callback delegate on a ThreadPool thread. Is there any way to make it use a custom ThreadPool? (For instance, Jon Skeet's CustomThreadPool.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not using `System.Threading.Timer`, no. Using `System.Timers.Timer` I believe you *could* if the thread pool in question implemented `ISynchronizeInvoke` accordingly. I believe the timer will call `BeginInvoke` on its `SynchronizingObject` to execute the callback accordingly. If a thread pool implemented `ISynchronizeInvoke` to mean "add the callback to the work queue" it should work fine.

(Mine doesn't do implement it, but it probably wouldn't be too hard to do. My thread pool is extremely primitive btw - or at the very least it's very old! - there are almost certainly better ones available now.)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I was hoping that you'd have some input.